# Flask-Login automatically logs in to a random account even in different browser

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am coding a project in Flask, Flask-Login and Flask-SQLAlchemy. The site uses Flask-Login to authenticate users, however users on the site are logged in to random accounts without signing in or registering. I tried changing the Secret Key and even tested in Incognito with a VPN.

My Users model:

```py
#Models
class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False, default=0)
    email = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), nullable=False)
    writings = db.relationship('WritingSubmission', backref='users', lazy=True)
    posts = db.relationship('BlogPosts', backref='users', lazy=True)
    role = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False, default="Member")
    role_color = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False, default="DDE6ED")
    role_background = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False, default="526D82")
    tokens = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, default=0)
```

Login Manager config:

```py
#Login Manager
from flask_login import LoginManager
from monkr.models import Users

lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = "auth.login_page"
lm.login_message = "You need to login first!"
lm.login_message_category = "warning"

@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return Users.query.get(int(id))
```

I have tried opening the site on 2 new devices not connected to the same network but it was logged in automatically to a random account.

Thank you for your help!